# Unexpected alert with message "undefined" after successfully calling simple function with arguments

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why the following code produces the alert box that I expect (RyeTofuRye), but then produces a second alert box with the message "undefined?"  At least that's what it's doing in the latest FireFox on my Windows 7 machine.

```
function makeSandwich(bread, meat) {
alert(bread + meat + bread);
}
var mySandwich = makeSandwich('Rye', 'Tofu');
alert(mySandwich);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are returning Nothing, the second alerts undefined!!
flow below:

```
function makeSandwich(bread, meat) {//step-3
    alert(bread + meat + bread); // alerting RyeTofuRy, step-4
    // am i returnign anything? nope!
    //adding a return (bread + meat + bread); resolves teh problem though
    }

var mySandwich = makeSandwich('Rye', 'Tofu');//start here step-1
alert(mySandwich);//step-2, step-5
```

Comment: Thanks, Eswar!  That was a perfect explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't return a value from `makeSandwich()`, so `mySandwich` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
function makeSandwich(bread, meat) {
return(bread + meat + bread);
}
var mySandwich = makeSandwich('Rye', 'Tofu');
alert(mySandwich);
```

Answer (score 0):

`makeSandwich` returns nothing. Change it to this:

```
function makeSandwich(bread, meat) {
    return(bread + meat + bread);
}
```